# Python not uploading to Database.dbo.table, but database.[username].table instead

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm having trouble uploading to MS SQL via Python, say database = db1, the table = table1, I want to upload to db1.dbo.table1, but instead my dataframe was uploaded to db1.[my windows username].table1, I'm assuming it's because I used default windows authentication? Any help ould be appreciated, thanks.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("Driver={SQL 
Server};Server=server1;Database=db1;")
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
df = somepandasdataframe
df.to_sql(table1,engine)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct behavior for SQL Server. Normally, when simply creating a table, such as `CREATE TABLE bob (Id int identity, dataValue bigint)`, SQL Server will assume the schema name (the portion you want to be .dbo.) to be the login name of the current user. This default can be changed when creating a user by setting that user's default schema.

However SQL Alchemy also handles this problem with the "schema" qualifier. From the documentation:

> SQL Server schemas sometimes require multiple parts to their "schema"
>   qualifier, that is, including the database name and owner name as
>   separate tokens, such as mydatabase.dbo.some_table. These multipart
>   names can be set at once using the Table.schema argument of Table:
>
> Table(
>       "some_table", metadata,
>       Column("q", String(50)),
>       schema="mydatabase.dbo" )

Comment: See [the SQL Alchemy documentation page here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#multipart-schema-names) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you elaborate on how to incorporate that into current code? I have: Table('table1',metadata(),schema='db1.dbo'); engine=create_engine(...);df.to_sql(table1,engine). But that didn't work for me.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it was the schema argument in pds.to_sql(), solved my problem, thanks again!